# What's a "JS data warehouse"?

Tags: javascript

On this MDN page:

- [Using data attributes - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

the reader is cautioned about using data attributes:

> Also, the [performance of reading data-attributes](http://jsperf.com/data-dataset) compared to storing this data in a JS data warehouse is poor.

What's a "JS data warehouse"?

Based on the jsPerf test case linked-to in the above quoted text, a "warehouse" is just a JavaScript object.

The source of the quoted text on the MDN page seems to be this blog post:

- [Using data-* attributes in JavaScript and CSS – Mozilla Hacks – the Web developer blog](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/10/using-data-attributes-in-javascript-and-css/)

Comment: Holy ****, that's a confusing usage of the term "*warehouse*". It has nothing to do with [data warehouses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse).

Comment: @Bergi It was so confusing I wasn't sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: This page is a wiki so it can be crowd-edited. It looks like someone has done that since May 8 2018 and it now says "JS object" instead of "JS data warehouse". VTC as no longer repro.

Comment: @TylerH But what if the chances of this becoming a 'self-fulfilling prophecy' (e.g. inspiring a 'JS data warehouse' SaaS startup unicorn) only _increases_ were we to close this question?! The only winning move is not to play!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on the jsPerf test case linked-to in the above quoted text, a "warehouse" is just a JavaScript object.

Yes. This is a one-off term used in this article to describe a JS object as a "warehouse" of data, it's not referring to any kind of accepted concept in the industry.

Comment: Any specific evidence or reasoning?